# facebook integration for sites

Tags: facebook

AFAIK, the following are not possible for now: (Assuming we have user A which has allowed us all permissions:)

1. Send a message to a A's friend
2. get A's friends email

Aside from the obvious "Like" button, what are the ways that an app can leverage facebook's graph API to increase traffic flow?

I find the Like button to be more of a broadcasting mechanism. I was wondering what are the ways that I can specifically tell user B, whom is a friend of User A, that he/she should come check out my site.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a story on the user's feed allowing his friends to see what you have to offer.

Comment: I want a personal one to one message. Is it possible that I do friends invitation anonymously?

Comment: You can add a 'share' button, allowing the user sending it to whom ever he chooses, along with a personal message.